# google calendar javascript api: how to create a calendar in my google account and not in oauth authenticated user?

Tags: calendar, google-oauth, google-api-js-client

I'm thinking on my scenario and there is a point I cannot manage to bring to a valid approach:

I have a web app where users log in and, among other things, they can create calendars. If this calendars are marked as publics, all users can see them.

I want them to be able to sync the calendars with their google calendar account. I have this already implemented using gapi.
The problem is when, after a while, any user updates an event of a calendar which other user had synchronized before. He is not going to see the changes in his google calendar, as I'm not able to send him updates since he is not logged into the app.

So, my idea was to create all calendars in our own account, and whoever wants to have it in their google account, just have to subscribe to it. I would do that with gapi.acl lib.

What I don't know how to do is: when the first user wants to syncronize the calendar, it should first be created in our own google account, so that the user will be able to subscribe to it...

**But how do I change the account where to create a calendar using gapi?**

Maybe it is a stupid question but I cannot manage to find out how to do it.

Thanks in advance!!!!

Answer (score 0):

> But how do I change the account where to create a calendar using gapi?

You cant, what you are trying to do is get offline access to a users Google calendar data. OffLine access means that your application can access the users account when the user is "offLine" as in not there. This being a fully automated functionality of your application.

You need to request permission of the user for "offline" access once that is granted you are given a Refresh token the refresh token can then be used to request a new access token when ever your application needs even if the user is "offline".

Your problem being that JavaScript is client side this means that the code is running in the users browser. Due to major security concerns offline access is not something you can request using JavaScript you need to use a server sided programming language.

> Maybe it is a stupid question but I cannot manage to find out how to do it.

I don't think its a stupid question but I do think there are some major wholes in your applicating design.

- You first need to think of if users really want you writing to their personal calendar account.
- Then you need to consider weather or not you want to be writing and sharing your personal calendar with a bunch of unknown users.
- There are also major limitations to the number of writes or inserts you can make to a single calendar per day so storing everyone's calendar data in your own calendar is going to not only messy but it may end up overloading your request limit.
- Once all that is added up have you considered the verification process this application is going to have to go though.  How will you justify your application to googles security review,  I am writing to a users calendar, I am storing users calendar data in my own personal calendar ....